# finding span inside this

Tags: jquery

im trying to change the display attribute of a span inside of a li using the find function of jquery....its not working and i think i know why....because the span isnt inside of the input element right? but im not sure how to fix it

heres my code:

```
$('form ul li input').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).find('span').attr('display', 'block');
    else
        $(this).find('span').attr('display', 'none');
});
```

i know all i need to do is make it so it searches the LI and not the INPUT....but im not sure how to do this.

heres the HTML for an li:

```
<li>

    <input type="checkbox" name="attack_strategies[]" id="strategy_4" value="4" /> 
    <label for="strategy_4">meditation</label>

    <span>

        <select name="attack_strategies_e[]" id="strategy_e_4">
        <option value="">How effective was it?</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>          
        </select>

    </span>

</li>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are right. Actually, an [`input` element *<sup>[HTML4 spec]</sup>*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) cannot have any children:

```
<!ELEMENT INPUT - O EMPTY              -- form control -->
```

You can use [`closest` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the ancestor `li` and then search the `span` from there:

```
$(this).closest('li').find('span').css('display', 'block');
```

There might be other ways to to find the `span` but that depends on your HTML structure, which we don't know.

Comment: i thought that would work but it didn't...i added the HTML to my OP if you could have a look i'd appreciate it a lot. you can see i just want to show the SELECT when the INPUT is checked.

Comment: nevermind i got it. its because i was using ATTR instead of CSS.

Comment: @scarhand: Right, fixed it too.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, **this** refer to the input field,  and  [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) documentation reads:

> Description: Get the **descendants** of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

So you can't use find in an input field because it can haven't `span` child.

You can use what [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) suggests.